# Qual è il significato di "impennarsi" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> I guardiani devono aver sganciato i guinzagli, perché il ringhio dei cani è vicinissimo. Coca-cola soffia sulla torcia. Scivolano giú sui pali, urtandosi e spingendosi, in un’oscurità stantia e informe. Non c’è altra via, perché i guardiani presidiano le scale a pioli. Il metallo brucia le mani. Le tavole **s’impennano**. I pali sono di fuoco. Scendere verso dove. I piedi che poggiano sul niente. La pelle delle mani che s’incendia – i calzoni che per l’attrito sprizzano scintille.

Si tratta di ragazzi che sono stati scoperti dai guardiani in un grattacielo in costruzione.  Credo che le "tavole" di cui parla il testo siano quelle delle impalcature per i lavori di costruzione. Ho cercato "impennare" e "impennarsi" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato nessuna accezione che possa far riferimento a delle tavole. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: potreste spiegarmi il significato di "impennarsi" nel brano sopra citato?

Comment: I personaggi di cui parli avevano per caso delle tavole da skateboard? Qual é il contesto storico?

Comment: @Easymode44:  Si tratta di ragazzini di origine italiana emigrati a New York nei primi anni del Novecento. Quindi, non avevano skateboard.

Comment: @Easymode44: Immagino che queste tavole fossero quelle delle impalcature per la costruzione del grattacielo.

Comment: @Easymode44: Forse il significato è che queste tavole si sollevavono verso l'alto quando i ragazzi vi cadevano sopra, non so.

Comment: Potrebbe essere, ma sembra una cosa davvero estemporanea...

Comment: @Easymode44: Non capisco cosa vuoi dire col tuo commento.

Comment: Credo che le tavole (non fissate) si sollevassero quando le persone in fuga ci correvano sopra

Answer (score 6):

Grazie ai vostri commenti credo di aver capito il significato dell'espressione usata nel testo.

Come si può vedere nei dizionari, il verbo ["impennarsi"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/impennarsi) si usa di solito per riferirsi a cavalli, imbarcazioni, aeromobili o veicoli che sollevano la parte anteriore verso l'alto. Il senso nel brano citato nella domanda è che le tavole delle impalcature per i lavori di costruzione, che probabilmente non erano fissate saldamente ai pali, si sollevavano quando questi ragazzi in fuga dai guardiani, scendendo velocemente sui pali, vi cadevano e correvono sopra.

Penso anche che l'autrice abbia scelto questo verbo (e anche altre espressioni presenti nel passaggio) per dare enfasi alla senzazione che aveva l'io narrante, cioè che tutto quello che stava accadendo diventava una difficoltà alla fuga. A pensarci bene, "impennarsi" mi sembra più efficace di "sollevarsi" per trasmettere questa sensazione al lettore.